# ReactJs: How to go back to a previous page NOT using Routes?

Tags: reactjs

I have a menu that has 3 options:

[image]

Each button is represented by a different React component, so I have 3 React components in the **AdminHomeView**:

```
export default class AdminHomeView extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handlePartnerAreaClick = this.handlePartnerAreaClick.bind(this);
    this.handleCampaignAreaClick = this.handleCampaignAreaClick.bind(this);
    this.handleImportAreaClick = this.handleImportAreaClick.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      partnerAreaVisible: false,
      campaignAreaVisible: false,
      importAreaVisible: false,
    };
  }

  handlePartnerAreaClick() {
    this.setState({
      partnerAreaVisible: true,
      campaignAreaVisible: false,
      importAreaVisible: false,
    });
  }

  handleCampaignAreaClick() {
    this.setState({
      partnerAreaVisible: false,
      campaignAreaVisible: true,
      importAreaVisible: false,
    });
  }

  handleImportAreaClick() {
    this.setState({
      partnerAreaVisible: false,
      campaignAreaVisible: false,
      importAreaVisible: true,
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <OptionsMenu
          showPartnerArea={this.handlePartnerAreaClick}
          showCampaignArea={this.handleCampaignAreaClick}
          showImportArea={this.handleImportAreaClick}
        />
        {this.state.partnerAreaVisible ? <PartnersView /> : null}
        {this.state.campaignAreaVisible ? <CampaignsView /> : null}
        {this.state.importAreaVisible ? <ImportView /> : null}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

When I click on the "Partners" button, React renders the **PartnersView** component, and this is how the page looks like:
(There is a list of all the previously created partners, represented by the **ListPartners** component, and a button, which shows the form to register a new partner).

[image]

This is the code of the **PartnersView** component:

```
export default class PartnersView extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.handleCreatePartnerClick = this.handleCreatePartnerClick.bind(this);

    this.state = {
      listPartnersVisible: true,
      formPartnerVisible: false,
      partners: [],
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() { ... }

  handleCreatePartnerClick() {
    this.setState({
      listPartnersVisible: false,
      formPartnerVisible: true,
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      {this.state.listPartnersVisible ? (
        <div id="list-container">
          <ListPartners partners={this.state.partners} />

          <div className="button-wrapper">
            <button onClick={this.handleCreatePartnerClick} >
              Register new partner
            </button>
          </div>
       </div>
      ) : null}

      {this.state.formPartnerVisible ? (
        <FormPartner />
      ) : null}
    );
  }
}
```

And finally, when I click on the "Register new partner" button, this is how the page looks like:
[image]

**However, when I click on the "Partners" button on the TOP menu again, I need to go back to the list of partners, but now, nothing happens when I click on this button (since React understands the user is in the PartnerArea anyway (first code)**.

**Does anyone know how I can go back to the list of partners?**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you considered creating a separate route for creating partners, rather than using the same route for two different functions?

Comment: Yes, but I can't do it because the original project is not mine, and it has no routes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using the [Fully Uncontrolled Component with a Key](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html#recommendation-fully-uncontrolled-component-with-a-key) pattern.

> In order to reset the value when moving to a different item ..., we can use the special React attribute
> called `key`. When a `key` changes, React will [*create* a new component
> instance rather than *update* the current one](https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html#keys).

You can use a react key on the `PartnersView` component in `AdminHomeView` to reset the component.

Since you want to simply reset the view, the key doesn't need to be anything special, and I suspect making it a random number would be sufficient enough (it only needs to be different than the last key)

```
<PartnersView key={Math.random()} />
```

but if this is a concern you can always use something like [uuid](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid) to generate truly unique keys.

```
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid';

...

<PartnersView key={uuidv4()} />
```

In the Code

```
render() {
  return (
    <div>
      <OptionsMenu
        showPartnerArea={this.handlePartnerAreaClick}
        showCampaignArea={this.handleCampaignAreaClick}
        showImportArea={this.handleImportAreaClick}
      />
      {this.state.partnerAreaVisible && <PartnersView key={Math.random()} />}
      {this.state.campaignAreaVisible && <CampaignsView />}
      {this.state.importAreaVisible && <ImportView />}
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit reactjs-how-to-go-back-to-a-previous-page-not-using-routes]

Answer (score 0):

Right now you are in formpartner. after adding formpartner , If you change the flag "formPartnerVisible" to false and change listPartnersVisible to true.  It will resolve the issue.

Comment: How can I do it? If I call the function setState twice, React will override the calls, and only consider the last one.